# How I get Translate value when I move object on Maya

Tags: python, maya

I creating a plug-in Node in Maya but I try to get real-time value when I move object.

Mycase : Translate X = 5.434  and I move it with Move tool by click holding the mouse on the arrow x axis, So value of Translate X will change to other value

Question : How I know how many Translate X change?

Thank you,
I'm not good at English if I explain hard to understand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RyCU.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maya, but I'd guess that the details of mapping from 2D screen to 3D scene coordinates will have to be worked out.  You'll need to transform your mouse gesture into an (x, y, z) displacement vector in 3D screen coordinates.

Comment: @duffymo Maya doesn't work that way.

Comment: I'll bet it does, but they've abstracted it away from you.

Answer (score 0):

I probably need a little more detail before I can fully answer this question *(eg is the plugin a custom transform node? or just a regular dependency node?)*

It doesn't look like you are using a custom MPxTransform node from what I can see, so this seems to be a question of how do you access a translate param from a transform node *(pCube3 in this case)*?

In general, do not think about this in terms of events. i.e. Whilst you might *think* you want to be notified when the *translateX* changes, that goes against the design of Maya's DG.

You actually need to have an attribute on your node with this information in it, because the first rule of the Maya API is: You can only access data within your nodes compute method, that is an attribute on your node. Accessing "pCube3.translate" would violate this rule!

*Using connections to access the value*

This assumes you are NOT using MPxTransformNode, and are using MPxNode *(or MpxLocatorNode, etc)*

On your MPxNode derived plugin type, you'll need to add a point attribute to your node definition *(do this within your nodes static initialise method you passed to MFnPlugin::registerNode)*.

```cpp
MFnNumericAttribute fn;
g_myTranslate = fn.addPoint("translate", "tr");
fn.setConnectable(true);
fn.setReadable(true);
fn.setWritable(true);
```

At this point, you have to jump out of C++ for a bit, and move to MEL *(or python)*, because you really can't do all of this in the API alone.

```
// a callback you can attach to a button, or menu item... 
global proc makeMyNodeAndConnectStuffUp() {
   // grab currently selected transform nodes
   $sl = `ls -sl -type "transform"`;

   // create one of your plugin nodes (replace "myPluginNodeType"
   // with the typename of your plugin). 
   $myPluginNode = `createNode "myPluginNodeType"`;

   // now create a connection from the transforms translate attribute, 
   // to the translate attribute of your node
   connectAttr ($sl[0] + ".translate") ($myPluginNode + ".translate");
}
```

Every time you move pCube3, the translate value will propagate down into your translate attribute on your plugin node *(so it will now be available within your compute)*

However, that probably isn't quite enough in of itself. Typically Maya will only call 'compute' when an output from that node is required. In other words, in the setup above, modifications to the pCube3.translateX param won't always propagate downstream to your node.

If you only need this attribute within a MpxLocator::draw() method *(or similar)*, then you'll want to flag that with Maya when defining the attribute:

```cpp
MFnNumericAttribute fn;
g_myTranslate = fn.addPoint("translate", "tr");
fn.setConnectable(true);
fn.setReadable(true);
fn.setWritable(true);

// will be updated prior to draw()
fn.setAffectsAppearance(true);
```

If however you want to use it as an input to some computation that produces an output, you'll need to use `MPxNode::attributeAffects()`, e.g.

```cpp
MFnNumericAttribute fn;

// just an example output attribute.... 
g_myOutput = fn.addPoint("output", "out");
fn.setConnectable(true);
fn.setReadable(true);
fn.setWritable(false);

g_myTranslate = fn.addPoint("translate", "tr");
fn.setConnectable(true);
fn.setReadable(true);
fn.setWritable(true);

// Now set up the internal node dependencies:
// "output" will be recomputed when "translate" changes. 
MPxNode::attributeAffects(g_myTranslate, g_myOutput);
```

you'll need some handling within your nodes compute, e.g.

```cpp
MStatus MyCustomNode::compute(const MPlug& requested_output, MDataBlock& block) {

  // if Maya wants us to compute the output
  if(requested_output == g_myOutput) {

     // grab handle and value from translate input attr
     MDataHandle inHandle = block.inputValue(g_myTranslate);

     // grab value 
     MVector translateValue = inHandle.asVector(); 

     // compute some result (multiplying by 2 as an example)
     translateValue *= 2.0;

     // grab pointer to output location
     MDataHandle outHandle = block.outputValue(g_myOutput);

     // write the output
     outHandle.setMVector(translateValue);

     // make sure you flag the output as clean!
     block.setClean(requested_output);

     // done
     return MS::kSuccess;
  }
  // otherwise pass to default
  return MPxNode::compute(requested_output, block);
}
```

*Using a custom MPxTransformNode*

Something tells me you *are not* using this plugin node type?
If you are, then the transform value would be available within your MPxTransformationMatrix::getMatrix method, or you will need to add a custom `MPxTransform::validateAndSet()` method to intercept the translate changes.

I doubt you are doing this *(custom transform nodes are a bit of a pain to be honest)*.

*Use MNodeMessage be notified of an attribute change on your node*

Yeah, you really do NOT want to do this, but it is possible.

This still requires a custom translate attribute to be connected to pCube3.translate, but we can set up a callback.

We can receive a notification when an attribute changes, however I'd strongly recommend only using this in emergencies *(because it usually causes more problems than it solves!)*.

```cpp
class MyCustomNode : public MPxNode {
public:

   MCallbackId callback;

   static void handler(MNodeMessage::AttributeMessage msg, MPlug &plug, MPlug &otherPlug, void *clientData);

   // initialise callback - do NOT use constructor!
   void postConstruct() {
     callback = MNodeMessage::addAttributeChangedCallback (thisMObject(), handler, this);
   }

   // delete the callback when the node is deleted
   ~MyCustomNode() {
      MNodeMessage::removeCallback(callback);
   }

};

void MyCustomNode ::handler(MNodeMessage::AttributeMessage msg, MPlug &plug, MPlug &otherPlug, void *clientData) {

   // if you need to access your node instance
   MyCustomNode* thisNode = (MyCustomNode*)clientData;

   // if the translate has changed
   if(plug == g_myTranslate) {

      MVector translateValue = plug.asMVector();
   }
}
```

*Use a scriptJob to receive a notification*

You can use the MEL command scriptJob to set up a notification when an attribute changes on pCube3. This is very similar to using MNodeMessage, however you can attach the callbacks to *any* node in the scene, even nodes you didn't write.

This is however really unpleasant, and comes with some pretty nasty performance implications. My advice would be to ignore this entirely!

hope that helps...